# SSL cert error when installing emscripten SDK on Windows

Tags: windows, python, ssl

When following the installation steps for emscripten SDK on a fresh Windows 10 the Python script fails to download `wasm-binaries.zip` with a SSL certificate error which kills the install:

```
Error downloading URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/win/048cf9424790cc525a7ea6da340820aae226f3b9/wasm-binaries.zip': <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

How do I solve this issue without modifying the SDK installer code?

## System info

- Windows 10 (https://app.vagrantup.com/StefanScherer/boxes/windows_10)
- Python 3.7.3 (emscripten installs 2.7 itself)
- Git for Windows 2.21
- Visual Studio 2017 Community with C++ workload

## Steps to reproduce

1. Install Windows 10
2. Install chocolatey
3. `choco install git.install`
4. `choco install python`
5. `choco install visualstudio2017community` and `choco install visualstudio2017-workload-nativedesktop` (C++ compiler)
6. `git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git && cd emsdk`
7. `.\emsdk.ps1 install latest`

## Fixes tried

On Mac I can run the provided script with Python `Install Certificates.command` but the Windows distro does not have it.

### Disable HTTPS verify

Setting env var `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY` to disable the SSL cert check doesn't seem to work.

```
$env:PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY = 0

Write-Host $env:PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY // "0"

.\emsdk.ps1 install latest
```